# pecl install apc gives me Makefile:195: recipe for target 'apc.lo' failed

Tags: php, php7

On a 16.04.6 LTS box `sudo pecl install apc` fails with:

```
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_variables.h:122:48: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘_zval_ptr_dtor’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 #define zval_ptr_dtor(zval_ptr) _zval_ptr_dtor((zval_ptr) ZEND_FILE_LINE_CC)
                                                ^
/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:711:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘zval_ptr_dtor’
     zval_ptr_dtor(&data);
     ^
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_variables.h:112:15: note: expected ‘zval * {aka struct _zval_struct *}’ but argument is of type ‘zval ** {aka struct _zval_struct **}’
 ZEND_API void _zval_ptr_dtor(zval *zval_ptr ZEND_FILE_LINE_DC);
               ^
Makefile:195: recipe for target 'apc.lo' failed
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
sudo pecl install apcu
```

Comment: Please explain **how** this works and **why** it helps! (and what is `pecl`?)

Comment: This worked well enough for me.  "APCu is APC stripped of opcode caching." https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.apcu.php

Comment: glad it did :) Not sure whoever set this to delete.. they may go back to school. 2 voted this to delete although this was the solution. You can just shake your had.